# Cannot restart socket

Tags: c#, sockets

I do not seem to be able to reconnect after a socket has been closed. There are several answers on the net but none seem to work.

I have a program that connects using the following code which was pretty much lifted from a Microsoft example.

```
private  void StartClient()
{
    DateTime time = DateTime.Now;              // Use current time
    string format = "ddd-d-HH:mm-ss";
    string timeString = time.ToString(format);
    // Connect to a remote device.
    try
    {                
        if (client != null)
            Stop();

        client = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
        var state = new StateObject { workSocket = client };

        // Connect to the remote endpoint.
        client.BeginConnect(AprsConfig.URI, AprsConfig.Port,
            new AsyncCallback(ConnectCallback), client);
        connectDone.WaitOne();

        string logInString = string.Format("user {0} pass {1} vers Web-{3} 1.0 filter {2}\r\n",
                                AprsConfig.Callsign,
                                AprsConfig.Password,
                                AprsConfig.Filter,
                                timeString);
        // Send data to the remote device.
        appendToDebugFile("Sent to server: " + logInString);

        Send(client, logInString);
        sendDone.WaitOne();

        // Receive the response from the remote device.
        Receive(client);

    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        // Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
        appendToDebugFile("StartClient failed : " + e.ToString());
        if (retryCount < 10)
        { 
            appendToDebugFile("Attempt to restart again");
            retryCount++;
            restartClient
        }
    }
    retryCount=0;
}
```

It connects properly without problems the fist time. Receive() calls itself again and so on. 
I do not think it is relevant but here is the code

```
private  void Receive(Socket client)
{
    try
    {
        // Create the state object.
        StateObject state = new StateObject();
        state.workSocket = client;

        // Begin receiving the data from the remote device.
        client.BeginReceive(state.buffer, 0, StateObject.BufferSize, 0,
            new AsyncCallback(ReceiveCallback), state);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        //Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
        appendToDebugFile("Receive failed : " + e.ToString());
    }
}
```

and

```
 private void ReceiveCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
 {
    try
    {
        // Retrieve the state object and the client socket 
        // from the asynchronous state object.

        var state = (StateObject)ar.AsyncState;

        if (!state.workSocket.Connected)
        {
            reStartClient("Error: state.workSocket.Connected =false - Restarting");
            return;
        }

        var client = state.workSocket;

        // Read data from the remote device.
        var bytesRead = client.EndReceive(ar);

        if (bytesRead == 0)
        {
            reStartClient("ERROR: bytes==0 - Restarting");
            return;
        }

        // quickly store the buffer
        storeBytes buff = new storeBytes(state.buffer, bytesRead);
        byteQueue.Enqueue(buff);
        string data = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(state.buffer, 0, bytesRead);
        client.BeginReceive(state.buffer, 0, StateObject.BufferSize, 0,
        new AsyncCallback(ReceiveCallback), state);
        // setoff the readBytes Thread
        readBytesWaitHandle.Set();
    }
    catch(IOException e)
    {
        appendToDebugFile("ReceiveCallback failed : " + e.ToString());
    }
}
```

I am rightly or wrongly assuming that if I get zero bytes read then the connection has failed so 
I try to close the connection and start again. here is the code which I got from another Stackoverflow answer.

```
 private void reStartClient(string reason)
 {
     appendToDebugFile(reason);
     if (client != null && client.Connected)
     {
         client.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);

         client.Disconnect(true);
         if (client.Connected)
             appendToDebugFile("We're still connnected");
         else
             appendToDebugFile("We're disconnected");
         client.Close();
     }
     client = null;
     // appendToDebugFile("Waiting 10 secs");
     // System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(10000);
     StartClient();
 }
```

As you can see I have been trying delays but that has not worked.

As it goes through  StartClient after restarting it seems to connect but throws an error when it tries to send. Here is a part of the log file

> Attempt to restart again Socket connected to 37.187.40.234:14580
>   Stopped 13/08/2014 14:18:18 We're disconnected Sent to server: user
>   2E0ATJ pass -1 vers Web-Wed-13-14:18-18 1.0 filter r/51.6/-.8/2000
>   -q/C
>
> StartClient failed : System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (0x80004005):
>   A request to send or receive data was disallowed because the socket is
>   not connected and (when sending on a datagram socket using a sendto
>   call) no address was supplied    at WebAPRS.PacketListener.Send(Socket
>   client, String data) in c:\Users\Alan\Documents\Visual Studio
>   2013\Projects\WebAPRS\WebAPRS\Connection.cs:line 188    at
>   WebAPRS.PacketListener.StartClient() in c:\Users\Alan\Documents\Visual
>   Studio 2013\Projects\WebAPRS\WebAPRS\Connection.cs:line 64 Attempt to
>   restart again Stopped 13/08/2014 14:18:18 Sent to server: user 2E0ATJ
>   pass -1 vers Web-Wed-13-14:18-18 1.0 filter r/51.6/-.8/2000 -q/C
>
> StartClient failed : System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (0x80004005):
>   A request to send or receive data was disallowed because the socket is
>   not connected and (when sending on a datagram socket using a sendto
>   call) no address was supplied    at WebAPRS.PacketListener.Send(Socket
>   client, String data) in c:\Users\Alan\Documents\Visual Studio
>   2013\Projects\WebAPRS\WebAPRS\Connection.cs:line 188    at
>   WebAPRS.PacketListener.StartClient() in c:\Users\Alan\Documents\Visual
>   Studio 2013\Projects\WebAPRS\WebAPRS\Connection.cs:line 64 Attempt to
>   restart again Stopped 13/08/2014 14:18:18

Hopefully somebody can tell me what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Maybe that 'Receive() calls itself again' and it's still listening on the socket when you try to close and reopen the connection?

Comment: Why are you calling `client.Disconnect(true)` (specifying that you're going to reuse the socket), and then `client.Close()` (releasing all resources)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most probably `connectDone` is a `ManualResetEvent` which was put in a *signalled* state on the previous connection attempt, and was never reset. This causes `WaitOne()` to not block, and a the code attempts to send data before the connection was established.

You could reset it prior to connecting:

```
// Connect to the remote endpoint.
connectDone.Reset();
client.BeginConnect(AprsConfig.URI, AprsConfig.Port, new AsyncCallback(ConnectCallback), client);
connectDone.WaitOne();
```

Alternatively you could use `AutoResetEvent` if no other threads monitor `connectDone`.

Comment: Well that worked in my test. If it does not work in anger then I will report back. In all my googling I never found that mentioned.

Comment: As to the other questions. The answer is that I do not know what I am doing. What is it that I should be doing in restartClient?

Comment: @AlanJohnstone There's nothing functionally wrong, it's just that `Disconnect(true)` says "I'm going to use this socket later" and immediately afterwards you use `Close()` which says "I'll never use _this_ socket again". I'd skip the `Disconnect(true)` call and "still connected" logging, and just `Close()` the thing.